# How to find numpy array shape in a larger array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
big_array = np.array((
  [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
  [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0], 
  [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]))

print(big_array)
[[0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

Is there a way to iterate over this numpy array and for each 2x2 cluster of 0s, set all values within that cluster = 5? This is what the output would look like.

```
[[0 1 5 5 1 5 5 1]
 [0 1 5 5 0 5 5 0]
 [0 1 5 5 1 5 5 0]
 [0 0 5 5 1 5 5 0]
 [1 0 5 5 1 5 5 0]]
```

My thoughts are to use advanced indexing to set the 2x2 shape = to 5, but I think it would be really slow to simply iterate like:
1) check if array[x][y] is 0
2) check if adjacent array elements are 0
3) if all elements are 0, set all those values to 5.

Comment: It's not clear what you consider to be "each 2x2 cluster of 0s" in the presence of overlaps, especially your example output is allowing some overlaps and rejecting others.

Answer (score 0):

```
big_array = [1, 7, 0, 0, 3]

i = 0
p = 0
while i <= len(big_array) - 1 and p <= len(big_array) - 2:
    if big_array[i] == big_array[p + 1]:
        big_array[i] = 5
        big_array[p + 1] = 5
        print(big_array)
    i = i + 1
    p = p + 1
```

Output:
[1, 7, 5, 5, 3]

It is a example, not whole correct code.

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice you need numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution by viewing the array as blocks.

First you need to define this function `rolling_window` from here https://gist.github.com/seberg/3866040/revisions

Then break the array `big`, your starting array, into 2x2 blocks using this function. 
Also generate an array which has indices of every element in big and break it similarly into 2x2 blocks.

Then generate a boolean mask where the 2x2 blocks of big are all zero, and use the index array to get those elements.

```
blks = rolling_window(big,window=(2,2)) # 2x2 blocks of original array
inds = np.indices(big.shape).transpose(1,2,0) # array of indices into big 
blkinds = rolling_window(inds,window=(2,2,0)).transpose(0,1,4,3,2) # 2x2 blocks of indices into big 

mask = blks == np.zeros((2,2)) # generate a mask of every 2x2 block which is all zero 
mask = mask.reshape(*mask.shape[:-2],-1).all(-1) # still generating the mask 


# now blks[mask] is every block which is zero..
# but you actually want the original indices in the array 'big' instead

inds = blkinds[mask].reshape(-1,2).T # indices into big where elements need replacing 
big[inds[0],inds[1]] = 5 #reassign
```

You need to test this: I did not. But the idea is to break the array into blocks, and an array of indices into blocks, then develop a boolean condition on the blocks, use those to get the indices, and then reassign.

An alternative would be to iterate through `indblks` as defined here, then test the 2x2 obtained from big at each indblk element and reassign if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt to help you solve your problem. My solution may be subject to fair criticism.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
m = np.array((
  [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
  [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]))
h = 2
w = 2
rr, cc = tuple(d + 1 - q for d, q in zip(m.shape, (h, w)))
slices = [(slice(r, r + h), slice(c, c + w))
          for r, c in product(range(rr), range(cc))
          if not m[r:r + h, c:c + w].any()]
for s in slices:
    m[s] = 5
print(m)

[[0 1 5 5 1 5 5 1]
 [0 1 5 5 0 5 5 5]
 [0 1 5 5 1 5 5 5]
 [0 5 5 5 1 5 5 5]
 [1 5 5 5 1 5 5 5]]
```